# Why to use $onInit in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In AngularJS, what is the purpose of the `$onInit` function if I can do the same initialization without that function?

For example this:

```js
module.component("myComponent", {
        ...
        controller: function() {
            const $ctrl = this;

            $ctrl.$onInit = () => {
                $ctrl.var1 = "hello";
                $ctrl.var2 = { test: 3 };
            }
        }
    });
```

Can also be done like this:

```js
module.component("myComponent", {
        ...
        controller: function() {
            const $ctrl = this;

            $ctrl.var1 = "hello";
            $ctrl.var2 = { test: 3 };
        }
    });
```

Is there some case where `$onInit` is necessary?

Comment: With the release of AngularJS V1.7, the option to pre-assign bindings to has deprecated and removed. Initialization logic that relies on bindings being present should be put in the controller's `$onInit()` method, which is guaranteed to *always* be called after the bindings have been assigned.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Per the [AngularJS docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.8/docs/guide/component)

> Called on each controller after all the controllers on an element have been constructed and had their bindings initialized (and before the pre & post linking functions for the directives on this element).

This gives you two guarantees:

1. All controllers on this element have been constructed
2. The pre & post linking functions for this element have not been executed

In contrast to your first method, where neither of these facts are guaranteed (though the second one is *highly* probable).

In addition, as a matter of style and readability, it makes it very clear to a potential reader/reviewer that this is code that you as the developer intended to run upon initialization of this controller.

Comment: Not just readability, but testing and extensibility as well.